# Android Emulator have blurry fonts

Tags: android-emulator, adb

I am using android emulator but the fonts in the virtual OS having blurry and broken fonts on every corner of the app.

They also having graphics issue all over the virtual operating system.

Strange thing about this issue is that when I take a screenshot of the emulator using windows snapshot tool I see blur and broken font, but when I take snapshot using bug report in android emulator setting there are no broken fonts.

Snapshot using windows snapshot tool:

[Snapshot using windows snapshot tool image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myFFG.png)

[Snapshot using windows shapshot tool image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWbZ9.png)

Snapshot using bug report tool in android emulator settings:

[Snapshot using bug report image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrCLU.png)

[Snapshot using bug report image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN4i5.png)

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: A scaling problem? Try to change the window size (you have to enable window frame)

Comment: Can you please explain in detail. One more thing if I also use scrcpy and then use it to cast my real hardware screen to my laptop the same thing happens my phone font gets displayed broken while actually it is not. https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

Comment: The screen shot from the bug report shows that the device resolution is larger than the window that displays the emulator. That is the main problem because this requires to scale down the screen content. Make sure the emulator size is the original emulator resolution or faction of two (e.g. 1/2 or 1/4 and so on).

Comment: @Robert I am unable to change resolution size, resizing windows does not help. Can you please explain the steps, required to change resolution size.

Comment: I tried using pixel 2 emulator with android 11 (Google Play) and in it google chrome does not work moreover pixel live wallpaper is also not working.